# Errors when compiling DJI Windows SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dji-sdk

The instructions mentioned that just compile and run the program using x86 architecture via Visual Studio 2017. But these errors shows up after compiling it. [Errors shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klkkw.png)

Any suggested solution to fix these errors?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

take this link to resolve your problem :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/

or go in "tool" then package manager NuGet, and to finish
the package manager console. and tip in console: 
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform -Version 6.1.9

... Good ?